# How To Resolve Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe.?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am using trying to insert result of select query into other table.

Explanation:
I have tried different workarounds to resolve this issue but none of them works for me.

1. I have use `add jar` command to add serdes to hive shell classpath.
2. I have moved all required jar files from /usr/local/hive/lib to hive class path which is located on hadoop's hdfs file system.
3. I also added environment variable to my .bashrc file.

After all of these tries I am still getting same error. any help will be appreciated.

Query:

```
insert overwrite table outbound_log_event partition(batch) select c_ip, mdatetime, mdate, mtime, file_name, raw_line, fprint, mapping, time_taken, cs_username, cs_auth_group, x_exception_id, sc_filter_result, cs_categories, cs_referer, sc_status, s_action, cs_method, rs_content_type, cs_uri_scheme, cs_uri_port, cs_host, cs_uri_path, cs_uri_query, cs_uri_extension, cs_user_agent, s_ip, sc_bytes, cs_bytes, x_virus_id, cs_ip, x_bluecoat_application_name, x_bluecoat_application_operation, file_name as log_type, mdate as batch from outbound_log_event_staging;
```

Exception:

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:140)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.initializeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:446)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:481)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:481)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.initializeMapOperator(MapOperator.java:442)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:119)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableDesc.getDeserializerClass(TableDesc.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.initializeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:355)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableDesc.getDeserializerClass(TableDesc.java:71)
        ... 32 more
```

Comment: Sometimes a ClassNotFoundException, is a symptom of a transitive dependency. Check your code for transitive dependencies. Are you using maven, or other build tool?

Comment: no there no code involved for know. because i am running query in hive shell. the issue is happening when job trying to start reducer.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolve above issue by setting hive.aux.jars.path in hive-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/Cellar/hive–1.2.1/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.jar</value>
  </property>
```